# Generate local variable to receive the return value of a method eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

for example I have this code

```
categoryCT.getInsertedItems();
```

and I want shortcut to generate code like this

```
List<Category> insertedItems=   categoryCT.getInsertedItems();
```

Comment: You can use Ctrl+1 it will give hints under this you can choose assign statement to new local Variable

Comment: I see add finally block

Comment: try This shortcut it will automatically assign (ctrl+2,l)

Comment: this shortcut didn't do anything!

Comment: shortcuts like  "ctrl+2, l" are a bit tricky since it depends a bit on timing here. One approach that works pretty good for me: ctrl down, 2 down (ctrl+2 at that point), release ctrl, L down (2+L at this point), release 2 and L. The cursor will also need to be inside `categoryCT.getInsertedItems()` since that's what you want to assign.

Comment: I saw quick assest menu and it also didn't work

Comment: Ctrl+1 works even in Netbeans if shortcuts are selected in Eclipse style.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Eclipse can't help you with the variable name but you can write:

```
insertedItems = categoryCT.getInsertedItems();
```

This will give you a compile error.

If you press <kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd> anywhere in this line, Eclipse will offer "Create local variable 'insertedItems'"

Fewest keystrokes to get the desired result:

- `catCT`<kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> -> `categoryCT`
- `.getII`<kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> -> `categoryCT.getInsertedItems()`
- `;`
- <kbd>Shift+Alt+Left</kbd> to select the whole method invocation
- <kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd> + select "Create new local variable"

Comment: Shift+Alt+Left to select the whole method invocation
Ctrl+1 + select "Create new local variable" these two steps do the job

Answer (score 7):

I'd add for **windows** users:

Press `ctrl+2` for the available options.

For ex. `ctrl+2+L` will assign your statement to a local variable.

Answer (score 4):

The shortcut that works on my Mac is <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> (lowercase L key)

Steps:

- Write the variable, Ex: `categoryCT.getInsertedItems();`;
- Select the entire variable definition;
- Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, leave the press and then press <kbd>l</kbd>(lowercase L key);

This will create the line `List<Category> insertedItems=   categoryCT.getInsertedItems();`.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl+2, L   will do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I saw `Alt+Shift+L`, but that works and if your right-hand assignment is the only thing on the line, you don't even have to highlight it

Answer (score 0):

Just uses eclipse's quick fix: Cmd+1. after type categoryCT.getInsertedItems(), then click Cmd+1 when the cursor is at the end.

Answer (score 0):

**Alt + Shift + V:** in **NetBeans**
Extracts an existing expression or statement into a new variable. For example, the statement appears multiple times so it should be introduced to a variable:

> textEmail.getText() 
>   String text = textEmail.getText()

Select statement then the Introduce Variable dialog appears.
Introduce Variable dialog
Enter the variable name and click OK.

*Note that the scope of the newly introduced variable is local.*

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA you can use ctrl + alt + l.

Answer (score 0):

**for me `option+command+L` worked on mac with apple chip.**

Alternatively, you can select your statement that you want to extract a local variable and right click then from menu options go to refactors
and you should be able to find the  **`Extract Local Variable`** as option.

you can refer the following image.
[image]