# Can eclipse autocomplete on the left side of assignment operator?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist

If I have typed out an expression that returns a known type, is there a way for eclipse to content-assist the creation of that type, potentially with templated variable names?

The screenshot below is an example of where this would be useful. You'll notice that if I hover my mouse over the `getModel()` method, it clearly states that it can only return a single type of `Map<String, Object>`. But if I then type <kbd>Ctrl-Space</kbd> with my cursor to the left of the `=`, nothing happens. Preferably, it would create the whole `Map<String, Object> model` that you see commented out, with `model` being templated so you could tab to it, and quickly enter your variable name.

I suppose it's even possible that it could infer the default variable name based on the getter method name...

[image: Example of where left side autocomplete would be useful.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could probably use the extract variable refactoring for this use case.

First type

```
mv.getModel()
```

Then go to *Refactor/Extract Local Variable* or just hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

It will then prompt you for variable name and after you hit enter you should get:

```
Map<String, Object> variableName = mv.getModel();
```

I know that the question is about content assist, but as far as I know it isn't possible to do this that way. Hopefully this is an acceptable alternative. If someone knows a better solution feel free to correct me.

Comment: While not technically content-assist, I think it does essentially solve the problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut for Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> (lowercase L key) See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36367780/6192949