# Can Pycharm autocomplete the left side of an assignment operator like eclipse?

Tags: python-3.x, ide, pycharm

Can Pycharm  autocomplete the left side of an assignment operator like [eclipse can with ctrl+shift+L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084316/can-eclipse-autocomplete-on-the-left-side-of-assignment-operator)?

Assume I have a function such as :

```
def file_list(self, pattern=None):
    ...
    return matching_filenames
```

I enter/auto complete the following code snippet elsewhere to use that function:

```
self.file_list(pattern)
```

Can PyCharm auto complete to something like:

```
matching_filenames= self.file_list(pattern)  // or even
file_list = self.file_list(pattern)
```

How?

I cannot find anything in the PyCharm docs at:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html

I know that Eclipse can do this, can PyCharm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. 
the default option should be:

1. select `self.file_list(pattern)` (mark it)
2. hit `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `V`
   it should add a new variable to your code.

[link for JetBrains's Pycharm documentation about this shortcut](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/extract-variable.html)

**side note:** there are a lot of useful shortcuts and something called live templates. i recommend reading on both since they help you write code faster and you will look cooler doing so.